# How to resolve a Django hstore error in tests

Tags: django, postgresql, hstore, django-tests

At some points in the app I'm collaborating on, a `HStoreField` is used (from `django.contrib.postgres.fields`). The app itself works normally, no build errors. But when I run tests, I get an issue:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: type "hstore" does not exist
```

From what I found, the issue is with Postgres, so I tried running the following command in psql: `create extension hstore;` on the `template1` database. The extension now shows when listing extensions (`\dx`):

```
hstore  | 1.5     | public     | data type for storing sets of (key, value) pairs
```

Since the error is still here, this obviously wasn't the solution. What should I try?

EDIT: I ran `create extension hstore;` on the `default` database from the settings file, too, verified it's created, but still get the same issue.

Comment: Run "create extension hstore" on the database you are connecting to. Placing it in template1 should cause it to be created in the next database you create assuming you don't use a template other than template1. However running in template1 will not create the extension for existing databases.

Comment: @Belayer did it, the extensions is there in the default database from my settings file, but I still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was when I opened up pdAdmin to take a better look. In my settings file, I have a default database, `mydb`. I ran `create extension hstore;` in psql on that database, but what I missed was that a new db was created for the tests: `test_mydb`. I connected to that db and ran the same command there, after which the tests started working.